# Explicitly describing the equivalence relation generated by $R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Here is an explicit construction of the equivalence relation generated by a relation $R$ (found in [Leinster's book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf)):

[image]

First of all, I don't understand the highlighted part. Where does this zigzag come from? Why is having such a zigzag equivalent to $a\sim a'$?

Second, why is the $\sim$ defined at the end indeed the equivalence relation generated by $R$? What would a rigorous proof of this fact be? I'm not even sure I understand what lies behind this definition. For example the statement $(a_0,a_1)\in S$ says that either $a\sim_R a_1$ or $a_1\sim_R a$ for some $a_1\in A$, and I don't see how this is relevant to the equivalence relation generated by $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book writes $x\to y$ for $(x,y)\in R$. It also uses $x\gets y$ for $(y,x)\in R$.

Since we're assuming that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation containing $R$, necessarily $x\to y$ and $x\gets y$ imply $x\sim y$, because $\sim$ is by assumption symmetric.

We're also assuming that $\sim$ is transitive. The “zigzag” in the example means

> suppose we have $a\to b$, $b\gets c$, $c\gets d$, $d\to e$, $e\gets a'$; then we must have $a\sim b$, $b\sim c$, $c\sim d$, $d\sim e$ and $e\sim a'$; since $\sim$ is transitive, we conclude that $a\sim a'$.

Thus every pair of elements “linked by a zigzag” must belong to $\sim$.

Now consider the set $\tilde{R}$ of pairs $(a,a')$ such that either $a=a'$ or there exist $a_0=a,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},a_n=a'\in A$ with either $a_{k-1}\to a_k$ or $a_{k-1}\gets a_k$, for $k=1,2,\dots,n$ (with $n\ge1$). Note that “either $a_{k-1}\to a_k$ or $a_{k-1}\gets a_k$” is the same as “$(a_{k-1},a_k)\in S$”, in the book's notation.

Then prove that $\tilde{R}$ is an equivalence relation.

Since clearly $\tilde{R}$ contains $R$, it is the equivalence relation generated by $R$, because it just contains what it must contain, that is, the pairs of elements linked by a zigzag.

Note: here I use $n\ge1$ by clarity; the text uses also $n=0$, which accounts for the pairs $(a,a)$, but it's a bit of a stretch for beginners.

Comment: Regarding the symmetry of $\bar R$. Suppose $(a,a')\in \bar R$. If $a=a'$, then $(a',a)\in \bar R$. Suppose $a\ne a'$. Then there are $a_0=a,\dots,a_n=a'$ s.t. what you wrote holds. To show that $(a',a)\in \bar R$, we need to show in particular that (1) either $a'\to a_1$ or $a_1\to a'$, and (2) either $a_{n-1}\to a$ or $a\to a_{n-1}$. I don't see why this should be true. We know that either $a\to a_1$ or $a_1\to a$, but this doesn't seem to imply (1) or (2).

Comment: And when proving the transitivity, there is the case when there exist $a_0=a,\dots a_n=a'$ s.t. $a_{k-1}\to a_k$ or $a_k\to a_{k-1}$ and also there exist $b_0=a',\dots,b_l=a''$ s.t. $b_{k-1}\to b_k$ or $b_k\to b_{k-1}$. In that case we need to prove that there exist $c_0=a,\dots,c_m=a''$ s.t. $c_{k-1}\to c_k$ or $c_k\to c_{k-1}$. I suppose we should define $c_i=a_i$ for $i=0,\dots, n$; $c_{n+j}=b_j$ for $j=1,\dots, l$. But why is it the case that either $a_n\to b_1$ or $b_1\to a_n$?

Comment: @user634426 Reversing all arrows in a zigzag gives another zigzag; concatenating to zigzags at a common end gives a zigzag.

Comment: Ok, I understood why $\bar R$ is an equivalence relation. (In the notation of my second comment, $a_n=b_0$, so either $a_n\to b_1$ or $b_1\to a_n$; and to prove the symmetry we reverse the given zigzag.) What remains to be understood is why $\bar R$ is contained in the equivalence relation generated by $R$. ("it just contains what it must contain" doesn't look convincing to me.)

Comment: @user634426 The first part about zigzags shows that any two elements linked by a zigzag must be in every equivalence relation containing $R$. Since $\tilde{R}$ just contains those pairs, it is the minimum one.

Comment: Does the statement "$a$ and $a'$ are linked by a zigzag" mean, by definition,  $(a,a')\in\bar R$? And going back, you write $x\to y$ and $y\to x$ imply $x\sim y$. But doesn't $x\to y$ alone already imply $x\sim y$? $x\to y$ means $(x,y)\in R$, and since $R\subset \sim$, we have $(x,y)\in\sim$ or equivalently $x\sim y$. (And I don't see how the symmetry of $\sim$ is used here.)

Comment: @user634426 Yes, that's the same, but “linked by a zigzag” is more expressive. For the “and”, read it in informal sense: any of $x\to y$ and $y\to x$ implies $x\sim y$.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to add all the pair to $R$ that you have to in order to make it an equivalence relation. Say $R$ has $(1,2),(1,3)$. The first stage is to make it symmetric by adding the reverse of all the pairs you have, so $(2,1),(3,1)$. Now add all the pairs needed to make it transitive. As we have $(2,1)$ and $(1,3)$ we need $(2,3)$. Similarly, we need $(3,2)$ and $(1,1)$. The zigzag is just a chain of pairs that forces us to add another pair to make the relation transitive.

Comment: @egreg Ok, I see.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a set $A$ is essentially the same as a partition of $A$. In order to turn $R$ into an equivalence relation, we might just define a partition of $A$ such that if $a \to a'$, then $a$ and $a'$ belong to the same subset in the partition, which will be the equivalence class $[a]$ of $a$.

So, let $a \in A$. Which elements of $A$ should belong to $[a]$? Well, clearly $a \in [a]$. Then, if $a_1 \in A$ is such that $a \to a_1$ or $a \leftarrow a_1$, we also want that $a_1 \in [a]$, because the two elements are related. But then all the elements that are related to $a_1$ must belong to $[a]$ as well. And then the elements related to those elements, and so on.

In general, an element $a'$ will belong the same class as $a$ if we can construct a sequence such as the one given in the book: we start from $a$ and at each step we choose an element that is related to the previous one (i.e., there is an arrow between them).